# nowrap item overflowing its box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Getting some strange behaviour with nowrap and list items. How do I get the padding to apply to the "Testing 123" li properly in chrome? (The "3" from testing 123 is outside the defined width and encroaches on the padding).

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is that the ul will be as wide as the widest li, hence the use of float: left. But at the same time I want to keep the dashed border, li padding and keep the text of each item on the same line, hence white-space: nowrap.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Testing 123</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    padding: 10% 15%;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #333;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T9emf/2/

Comment: Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`: http://jsfiddle.net/T9emf/3/ But you might want to aware that percentage margin may still cause problem, because there's no `width` information in `ul`, so any page redraw may cause `li`s to resize.

Comment: @Passerby that fiddle still has the same problem I'm afraid.

Comment: Using Chrome 27 I can see the render is correct; However, turning `display`/`width` on and off in DevTools will cause the layout to shift between several forms. If you don't see the "correct" layout, turn off and on `display` in DevTools. As I've stated, the root problem is that you set `li`s to have percentage padding, but there's no computable `width` information on `ul`.

Comment: @Passerby I think I get it, I figured the width information on the ul would take it's cue from the li, but that in turn is confused by the padding. Essentially there is no point of reference for it to work from so it takes it's best guess?

Comment: Yes. `ul` is auto-widthed, but `li` uses percentage padding, so when browser need to decide the actual padding, it is confused. The best guess would be to recursively draw `li` and calculate the width and redraw and re-calculate and so on. For your problem, I'll suggest you to use `em` unit in padding.

Comment: Beautiful, wish you'd put this as an answer, I'd credit you with it fi you'd like to repost your answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, extending from comment:

The root problem is that, your `ul` is auto-width-ed, but your `li`s use percentage padding, so when browsers come to render `li`, it needs to calculate how many actual padding should give, but then find that it can't, for there's no width info on their parent.

On this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9emf/3/, use Chrome DevTools to toggle `display:inline-block` and `width:auto` on and off repeatedly and observe the `li`s getting different size. The reason for that is since browser can't directly decide how many padding should give, it *may* try to decide later, so whenever layout changes, the `li`s may shift.

To fix this problem one possible way would be to give absolute padding to `li`s, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/T9emf/4/

```css
ul {
/*    float: left;*/
    display:inline-block;
}

li {
    padding: 1ex 1em;
}
```

Adjust the padding value to meet visual sweet spot.

The upside of `em` is that it has the possible to zoom in and out nicely, as it is a percentage unit bind to font size.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `width:100%;` to the style of "li" will resolve your problem.
The reason is that, the "li" element has a "10" left padding, but the border is drawn with the exact width of the text. Then it looks like the text overflows.

Comment: It's better than it was, but still not quite there. Setting to 100% will give you the width of the ul (i.e. largest li + any padding) which isn't what I want. Thanks for trying.